# how to display firebase val on a html like counter with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm training do display the current value from my firebase database
on to my HTML counter.
the problem is that I see only the current clicks and not the total clicks 
in the console, I can see the database value + 1

```js
     var bunnyData = null;
     function thumbsUpBtn(val) {

            var count  = document.getElementById('like').value;
            var new_count  = parseInt(count ,10) + val;
           
            if (new_count  < 0) {
                new_count  = 0;
            }
     
            
            var videosList = firebase.database().ref().child('videos');
     
            videosList.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                    var allVideos =  snapshot.val();
                    bunnyData =  allVideos.bunny;                     
                    console.log( bunnyData.likeCount);
                    WriteStatsToPage();

                });
     
                onclick            
                videosList.child("bunny").set({
                  likeCount : bunnyData.likeCount+1,
                  dislikeCount : bunnyData.dislikeCount,
                  viewsCount : 100

                });
     
        function WriteStatsToPage(){
                    $("likeNUmber").html[bunnyData.likeCount];
        }

            document.getElementById('like').value = new_count ;
            return new_count ;
        }
```

```html
                        <button id="thumbsUp" onClick="thumbsUpBtn(1)">
                        <img class="likeImg" src="Like.png" >
                         <input id="like" value="0" ></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Transactions and Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

> Transactions are useful when you want to update a field's value based
>   on its current value, or the value of some other field. You could
>   increment a counter by creating a transaction that reads the current
>   value of the counter, increments it, and writes the new value to Cloud
>   Firestore.
>
> A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by
>   any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete().
>   In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire
>   transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and
>   another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore
>   retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction
>   runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

```
// Create a reference to the SF doc.
var sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

// Uncomment to initialize the doc.
// sfDocRef.set({ population: 0 });

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then(function(sfDoc) {
        var newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```